# Customize Title Bar (Colored,Text,icon etc) in dialogBox foe WinCE 6.0

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, windows-ce

Hey i am new bie in winCE and working on 6.0 version, is there anyway to change the look and feel of dialog title bar in wince , i have tried with WM_NCPAINT message but it is not there in wince....
So is that any other way to do the same...??

Thanks,
Mukesh

Answer (score 1):

Does your OS include skinnability support?  If so you can skin the Windows to look like you want. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa459146.aspx) for more details.

Comment: We can do this at OS level which will change the whole theme...but this wont be worht fulll i want to do this at app level...